# Chrome DevTools Enable/Disable Javascript not showing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

- Chrome Version  73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)

As stated in title, I cannot find the Enable/Disable Javascript checkbox in dev tools.
I searched and couldn't find any info on this feature being removed (maybe I mislooked?)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can type `chrome://settings/content/javascript` in the adressbar and get the settings there.

You also have an option under Debugger to the right in the image you've provided.

Furthermore you can easily set site specific setting by clicking the lock to the right of the URL > Site Settings.